# SP13: Number of People Accessing Document

Tags: document-library, document, access, auditing

I will like to find out how many people are viewing my document within a document library.  I thought I could see it by choosing the ellipse per document and the number will appear in the dialog box that appears.  I know there is "Shared With:", however, I do not want to see who has access but rather who has recently accessed the document within the last 30 days or so.

Can anyone help me with this issue?  I am currently using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context menus do not show this type of information. You may want to explore the "Most Popular Items" option in the Library Ribbon, Share & Track section and/or the Popularity Trends found in the Site Settings, Site Administration section.  However, to get more specific details you will likely need to enable/setup auditing and examine those reports.  Good luck!